# what is the benefit to using mongoose .exec?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
  User.find().exec(function (err, users) {
    if (err){
      callback(err);
    } else {
      callback(users);
    }
  });


  User.find(function (err, users) {
    if (err) {
      callback (err);
    } else {
      callback(users);
    }
  });
```

What is the benefit of using the top code? both seem to work equally well

Answer (score 4):

They are identical and there's no benefit in your example

When you do not pass a callback to find function it won't execute but instead returns a query then you need to use exec()

```
var query = User.find();
```

now you can add some more criteria

```
query.where({age: 15});
```

and some more

```
query.select({name:1}); // or {firstname:1, lastname:1} etc.
```

now you've built up your query so to get the results you need to execute it.

```
query.exec(function(err, users){

});
```

But you can also do this like

```
User.find({age:15}, {name:1}, function(err, users){

});
```

Above is identical to

```
User.find({age:15}, {name:1}).exec(function(err, users){

});
```

since there's no callback in find function it will return query which means no results, exec will give you the results